# What is the required package version format in helm3?

Tags: package, format, kubernetes-helm

If I call `helm package ... --version <some_version>` I sometimes get `Error: Invalid Semantic Version`. How does a required package version look like in helm? Can someone provide me with a valid format?

Answer (score 3):

Helm uses `Semantic Versioning 2` standards.

```
**MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH**
```

Eg: 1.7.29, 3.14.159

> Ref:
> https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/conventions/#version-numbers
>
> Ref: https://semver.org/